# make union in laravel as a database table

Tags: php, database, laravel, model, eloquent

I have this code in a laravel project

```
$state_query = Advertisement::active()
            ->notExpired()
            ->inTime()
            ->network($network)
            ->textbook($textbook, $textbook_category_id, $book_category_id)
            ->grade($grade)
            ->state($state_id);

        $city_query = Advertisement::active()
            ->notExpired()
            ->inTime()
            ->network($network)
            ->textbook($textbook, $textbook_category_id, $book_category_id)
            ->grade($grade)
            ->city($city_id);

        $district_query = Advertisement::active()
            ->notExpired()
            ->inTime()
            ->network($network)
            ->textbook($textbook, $textbook_category_id, $book_category_id)
            ->grade($grade)
            ->district($district_id);


        $result = $state_query
            ->union($city_query)
            ->union($district_query);
```

now, I want to make "$result" variable as a database table and use "where" and "sum" eloquent functions on it
how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Simply make a collection :
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections
The results of Eloquent queries are always returned as Collection instances.

Comment: in 'advertisements' database table I have 'daily_budget' field, now when i use "sum('daily_budget) as d_sum" in "$result" i give this error:
```
The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns (SQL: (select sum(`daily_budget`) as aggregate from `advertisements`
```